# Изменить значения нескольких кнопок в Cypress

Tags: javascript

При написании теста на Cypress столкнулся со следующей проблемой.
Есть несколько(количество кнопок каждый раз может отличаться) кнопок с атрибутом `aria-checked="true"` нужно для каждой из них установить значение false для данного атрибута.

для одной кнопки делаю так:

```
    cy.get('[aria-checked="true"]')
    .type('aria-checked', {
        parseSpecialCharSequences: false,
      })
```

вопрос в том можно ли и как сделать так что бы данное изменение применялось для всех кнопок со значением true

Comment: как и описано я пишу тест на сайпресе, метот type это стандартный метод сайпреса

Comment: Если честно ни разу не работал с этой либой, но судя по документации вам может помочь метод [find](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/find)